# How to design a table in two layered structure, make the x-axix on the top of all x-axis data and make all text horizontally vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to design my table like below screen shot.

[image]

Right now my tbale looks like this -

[image]

As you can see first column refers issuetype\assignee. Here issuetype is y-axix and assignee is x-axix. So I need to design it like, in place of Type 1, Type 2, Type 3 etc all assignee name needs to be placed and in place of Assignee 1, Assingee 2 etc all issue type needs to be placed.

IssueType in my table are: Subtask - create IR, change of address etc

Assignee: aziah.purwitasar etc

I am unable to achieve such format. I am using twitter bootstrap, I don't know using bootstrap this is possible or not. If not plain html + css would be fine too.

Can someone please help me to design such structure. A fiddle demo would be really helpful.

Hey that helps. But now there is a border problem exist in chrome.

Firefox coming exactly as I want to.

[image]

Chrome as you can see border is coming in issueType column too. But we set rowspan=2 so it should not come. Whats the issue ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, i think you can need this:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Assigne</th>
    <th colspan="5">Issue Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Type1</td>
    <td>Type2</td>
    <td>Type3</td>
    <td>Type4</td>
    <td>Type5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assigne1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assigne2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assigne3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey that really helped. Thanks. Just one more issue. Can you please check why a border is coming in issueType column for chrome ? I have updated my answer with two more screen shot. Please check.

Comment: Hey, in my answer I can't see any border in chrome, please you check my answer in chrome..

Comment: yes because you added 5 <td> for first row. so for you first border not coming.But for me first <td> coming blank and if I remove blank <td> then Type 1 , Type 2 shifted to left..

Comment: please you can post your link, then i will check and figgure out your problem.